# Is there a way to group or organize friends within Diablo 3?

Tags: diablo-iii

My friends list has grown quite a bit since launch and now I'm having a hard time keeping track of who is who.

Is there a way to organize my friends into groups or can I rename the contacts to something I'll remember?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, at the moment there is not way to organize, group or renaming friends. If you want to take some notes about your friends that help remember who is who, use Notepad++ (or any similar program) or paper.